# Simple gradient in Android

Tags: java, android, gradient

I'm kinda new to Android, and I'm looking to create a really simple gradient of 2 colors, from top to bottom, display it on the view, and maybe save it as an image. I really didn't find an answer that suits my needs, I'm really looking for the simplest and most straight-forward way.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to create a simple Shape template in XML, and then use it in any view you want, like this:

shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:type= "linear"
        android:startColor="#474946"
        android:endColor="#181818"
        android:angle="270"/>

</shape>
```

then in your view tag just add:

```
 android:background="@drawable/shape"
```

Comment: What is "shape.xml"? I've tried to create it but didn't really manage to use it..

Comment: Put it in your drawable folder and just use it as if it was a normal png file (as shown in  the example).

Comment: shape.xml is the XML layout file that will serve as a reusable template for any view you create. You can name it as you like. You just create a blank XML file (typically somewhere in the res/ foldre), insert this code as an example, and you will see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer in two parts creating gradient and the displaying it.

To create gradient Create a new xml file in your drawable folder and name it whatever you want. In this case i will call it myGradient.xml.
Open myGradient.xml file and paste the code below which will help create two color gradient. You can change the values of color to what you need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:bottom="6px" android:right="4dp">

    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#d7009482"
            android:endColor="#ad1c4e9b"
            android:centerX="100%"
            android:centerY="150%"
            android:type="linear"
            android:angle="135"/>
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

This will give you output below.
[Gradient with two colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAtwD.png)

The second part will be to display this gradient in view.
Open your view and set background to be the gradient.

```
android:background="@drawable/myGradient
```

Hope that will help you

Comment: I believe `angle` should be 180 for the OP's case.